# Can I cause thermal shutdown (without heating device)

Tags: android

For some weird reason I need to check out shutdown process when platform request thermal shutdown. Does anyone know how I can simulate that without actully puting my device in fire?

I tried changing temp value for battery thermal zone sensor, but that didn't work.

Comment: Interested in the wierd reason...

Comment: @Shivam - Could you give us a few more details, like which platform are you trying this on?

Comment: Are you running a custom ROM?  Changing the thermal results from the driver might do it.  I'm assumign the weird reason is using a device in a high temperature environment?  In that case I wouldn't make any assumptions of clean shutdown-  you can overheat so much that you just kernel fault.

Comment: @Gabe, Yes I am. Other then making changes to HAL drivers I have access to do anything on device. Do you have any link that points how can I change results from driver?

Answer (score 0):

Internally, vendors do this by using a heat chamber at the system level and a heat gun and/or a soldering iron at the board/component.  Typically issues are bogus sensor reads/bad sensors, bad fans/power supplies (have local spares ready--shipping from China can be slow these days), and blocked air-flows.  Bi-passing thermal protection is dangerous, as is testing only the software (google Therac-25 to see what happens when software engineers get arrogant).  System can and do catch fire!